# How to call the same webmethod on either of two .NET webservices from the same client-side code

Tags: vb.net, web-services, inheritance, soap

I have two .NET SOAP web services which contain a variety of methods.  Of these, they have some in common, for instance:

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
Public Function DoStuff() As Long
   'Do server-side stuff
End Function
```

, and I want to be able to call this method on **either** of them from the **same** client-side code, which is used in different circumstances.

I've tried this:

- make both web services inherit from a parent one,
- override the relevant methods in each one

I was able to do this and compile.

However, when I instantiate the relevant child web service in each of the two separate scenarios, intending to pass that into the reused client-side code as an argument or a property, type conversion fails, saying that the child type can't be converted to the parent type.

Should this approach be possible in principle?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe what you are suggesting is possible with the basic setup you have described.

When you add a service reference to a project, Visual Studio creates proxy objects for the parameters being passed in. For example, if you look at the parameter being used for MyService1.DoStuff you will see it's type is MyService1.DoStuffParameter, the MyService2.DoStuff has a parameter of MyService2.DoStuffParamter. Therefore the two parameters are different (regardless of if they have the same properties).

There are two ways to get around this...

1. Add a class library to your webservice solution and define the DoStuffParameter in there, then reference the Class library in your client application. You'll notice next time you update the service references Visual Studio is able to realise that your client already knows what MyClassLibrary.DoStuffParameter is, and therefore doesn't bother proxying it. Instead, intellisence will show the parameter type is now MyClassLibrary.DoStuffParameter for both services.
2. Probably an easier solution, have a third Service which accepts the DoStuffParameter, along with which sub service it needs to go to. Then you only have one service reference in your client application, meaning it's always the same type.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Please could you elaborate a little on option 1?  Do you mean replicate the proxy methods that get generated in Reference.vb for the web services in a new class?